# Достать из файла классы Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы указываю игре файл, она могла загрузить из него классы, и использовать внутри себя? Если возможно, то как?\

Есть условная игра, она должна уметь доставать из .cs файла классы, и вызывать их методы. При этом, Это именно файлы исходного кода, а не предкомпилированные.

Comment: Если под файлом подразумевается сборка, то да, можно.

Comment: Как машина не может прочесть написанный по людски не компелированный `.cs`, так и человек не может читать откомпилированный код для машины, разве что названия классов и функций, всё остальное белебирда из символов.

Comment: @Yaroslav вы никогда не слышали про runtime компиляцию?

Comment: Нет, только подозревал =D  Тема очень специфическая (особенно для видеоигр). Читая каким языком написан вопрос, мне кажется, что человек пытается решить свою некую задачу не оптимальным способом который он придумал. Лучше бы он описал какую задачу он так решает.

Comment: @Yaroslav Можно это назвать модами для игры, как FML. но если в случае с FML используется java, сидящая в своей виртуалке и везде работающая одинаково, то в нашем случае это c#, причём целевых платформы 2 (PC/Android) И я сомневаюсь, что Android прочитает собранный exe или dll